# SAMSUNG refuses to honor their warranty. How to proceed?

Tags: united-states, consumer-protection, warranties, breach-of-contract

I bought a SAMSUNG flagship Android device from the world's largest retailer (Walmart).

The SAMSUNG device is now failing in multiple ways.

I have repeatedly contacted SAMSUNG, and SAMSUNG refuses to honor their warranty because Walmart does not print the IMEI on their receipts.  Instead of honoring the date on the receipt, SAMSUNG is calculating the end of the warranty based on the original manufacture date at the overseas factory.

The purchase was conducted in the United States at a Walmart retail store.  I have the original receipt from the cash register.

SAMSUNG does not dispute that I bought a SAMSUNG device with the exact model number of the device I have.  They claim that I have no way to *prove* that the device in my hand is the device I purchased less than a year ago, because Walmart does not print the IMEI on the receipt.

Does anyone know the best way to proceed?

---

UPDATE

I spoke with the manager at Walmart, and she insisted they have no way to print me a receipt or document with the IMEI number on it.  I even asked her to write a special letter for me, and she refused.

I also spoke with SAMSUNG again, and once again, they refused to honor their warranty without an IMEI printed on a receipt.

So, legally, how do I proceed?

Comment: If Samsung tells retailers that this is a necessity and they didn't do it, then your beef is with Walmart and not Samsung. See if you can get records from them that prove your receipt was connected to the phone you have. I can't imagine they wouldn't have that in their system somewhere. And if they don't, that's a serious issue with how they're processing phone sales.

Comment: @animuson Do you know of a way to find out if Samsung requires this of retailers?  Samsung never stated that they do.  Samsung only stated that since I can't absolutely prove that my receipt is for my device, Samsung will not honor their warranty.

Comment: Does it matter? Your time is probably better spent trying to get better proof of purchase from Walmart, even if Samsung didn't make this clear. Not printing the IMEI of your purchase on the receipt is the equivalent of cutting the serial number off a product box before selling it to you. It is the responsibility of the retailer to explain warranties and ensure you have all the documentation required to use them.

Comment: It feels like there is some background missing here, such as "Samsung is calculating the end of warranty from the manufacture date"  Can you fill in the missing pieces?  What do the terms of the warranty state about determining its term?

Comment: If Wallmart don't print the IMEI whats to stop someone buying another one, and then taking back the old one the day after?

Comment: @Tim Integrity?

Comment: @BenVoigt I have updated the question in response to your comment.  Thanks.  I am working to locate a copy of the actual written warranty to add even more details.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - It wouldn't stop some people! ;)   But note, that was not a suggestion for your issue.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of Walmart mentioning the manufacturer warranty in any of their advertisements?  It's entirely possible to be ineligible for a warranty due to a defect in the relationship between manufacturer and seller (in particular, it seems common for manufacturers to only honor invoice date from authorized dealers, and for purchases from others to use either manufacture date or date the unauthorized dealer made the purchase from an authorized distributor -- I don't know whether these hold up in court)

Comment: In extreme cases (nontransferable warranty) you might not even be eligible for warranty measured from the manufacture date -- if your dealer isn't authorized, then you aren't considered the original purchaser, the first time the product left the authorized supply chain would count as the original purchase.  However Walmart is [listed by Samsung as an Authorized Reseller](https://www.samsung.com/us/peaceofmind/authorized_resellers.html)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Is there a different interpretation of the last sentence of my comment?

Answer (score -2):

So their story is that there is evidence you bought a Samsung device with serial number ABCDEF, and you have in your hands a broken Samsung device with the serial number ABCDEF, but they claim there is no evidence that your broken device is the one that was purchased. In other words, they claim that you somehow managed to lay your hands on *two* Samsung devices with identical serial numbers, and you are trying to trick them into repairing the wrong device for free.

That's ridiculous.

Go to a small claims court.

Comment: The question says it is the same **model number**, not "serial number" i.e. the IMEI. It is not a unique identifier at all. You could buy a dozen phones with the same model number at a dozen places in a dozen months, so this is not a helpful answer.

Comment: I read it as their story being you have no evidence that you bought device serial number ABCDEF on date X, i.e. you have no evidence that the warranty for that specific device started on that date. So absent proof of a date we'll assume you bought it on the day we manufactured it, and that means you're out of warranty.

Answer (score -3):

If Samsung won't fix it, return it to the store. The store can't sell you faulty goods just like Samsung isn't supposed to.

Comment: Why downvote this?

Comment: It's marked as "US". In the UK I would expect that you have rights as a consumer that last longer than the manufacturer's warranty. In the USA, not sure at all.